# How to get the UIView that has requested to become the first responder?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, first-responder

In my app I have lots of UITextFields and UITextViews into which the user enters data. When the user taps on a field it becomes the first responder and the keyboard shows up nicely. When the user then taps on a different field (after having modified the current field) then the keyboard goes away and the current field stops being the first responder. However the field that was tapped does not immediately becoming the new first responder and the keyboard closes.

In my app, after a field is modified, it recalculates all the data and resets the values in all the other fields. I'm thinking that this is what is causing the newly tapped field to loose it's first responder request. There are some fields that are not affected by a recalculation and these behave correctly (that is they immediately get focus and keyboard remains open). So I'm pretty sure that changing the value or some property of the field is resetting the pending first responder request.

How can I detect if the field is pending in the first responder queue (if there is such a thing)?

And how can I make changes without removing it from this queue?

Comment: There is no "first responder queue". Normally, if the user taps on a field, if the keyboard was already showing, it doesn't go away. So _you_ must be making it go away. You need to think about why that is.

Comment: Yeah... Secondly, what exactly is the problem you have here? Or what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: When I tap on another UITextField the resignFirstResponder() for the current field is called by iOS, not my code (as far as I can tell). I'm doing the update to other fields from the textFieldDidEndEditing() method. So I'm not closing the keyboard (at least not directly).

Comment: My goal is to let the user change focus from one field to the next and the values all update in between. Currently when they tap the next field all fields loose focus, updates happen and you have to tap again on the next field to modify it.

Comment: The doc for UIResponder seems to hint at a queue with the .next property described as: `Returns the next responder in the responder chain, or nil if there is no next responder.` But I can't see how to use that or relate it to an actual field.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem. My code was setting .isEnabled to false and then resetting it back to true. This is what was causing the field to be dropped from the first responder chain. My code shared the same path for viewing and editing and it initially set a field as disabled and if we were in edit mode it then set it to enabled. Fixing this to just setting it to enabled, without the initial blanket disable, fixed the issue.

So the bottom line is that flicking the .isEnabled switch will remove the the field from the responder chain.